# Installation problem using Grafana 7.5 on AKS

Tags: grafana, azure-aks, grafana-loki

We are deploying version 7.5 of Grafana loki-stack using helm on AKS server.
The problem that we are facing is the following when we install helm chart. These is the error message that we obtain in the replica-set

```
Warning  FailedCreate  12s (x13 over 33s)  replicaset-controller  Error creating: admission webhook "validation.gatekeeper.sh" denied the request: [azurepolicy-k8sazurecontainernoprivilegees-d30fc4a5d3050e7c7bd6] Privilege escalation container is not allowed: grafana-sc-dashboard
[azurepolicy-k8sazurecontainernoprivilegees-d30fc4a5d3050e7c7bd6] Privilege escalation container is not allowed: grafana
[azurepolicy-k8sazurecontainernoprivilegees-d30fc4a5d3050e7c7bd6] Privilege escalation container is not allowed: grafana-sc-datasources
(reverse-i-search)`he': helm upgrade --install --namespace=mon-eval loki . --set grafana.enabled=true,prometheus.enabled=true,prometheus.alertmanager.persistentVolume.enabled=false,prometheus.server.persistentVolume.enabled=false,loki.persistence.enabled=false
```

Any suggestion about how we could fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The cluster admin activated the Azure Policy Addon (Gatekeeper) on this cluster. The policy `k8sazurecontainernoprivilegees` is blocking the containers `grafana, grafana-sc-dashboard & grafana-sc-datasources`.

You have some options now:

1. Ask the Admin to exclude the namespace from the policies (not recommended)
2. set `allowPrivilegeEscalation: false` inside the values.yaml at the securityContect sections [here](https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/grafana/values.yaml#L102) and [here](https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/grafana/values.yaml#L102).